# postgres 11->12 upgrade problems with pg_attrdef

Tags: postgresql

Running into an issue upgrading a really old postgres server that started at v8 and is no v11.

```
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 275; 1259 6116335 VIEW table_pk_seq postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: column a2.adsrc does not exist
LINE 17: "regexp_replace"("a2"."adsrc", 'nextval\(''|''::regclass...
```

It's tied to the following release notes

```
Remove obsolete pg_attrdef.adsrc column
```

I'm having a hard time finding where this is coming from. I've dumped all the dbs and grepped for asdrc with no luck.

Comment: Look at the definition of the view named table_pk_seq.

Comment: so the regexp_replace is there when i view that but I have no idea what to do so i can upgrade

Comment: It’s best to think about whether this view is needed at all and for what purpose it was created. It may be outdated and not used for a long time.

Comment: thanks.. that was it.. for some reason i thought that view was needed by postgres due to the name and not something that probably got created years ago and just left over after many upgrades

Answer (score 0):

Your database contains a view on catalog tables. Catalog tables change from version to version, so these views can be expected to break during an upgrade. The solution is to drop the view before you upgrade, and to create an equivalent view after the upgrade (or even better - do without a view on catalog tables).

In the case at hand, consider replacing

```
a2.adsrc
```

with

```
pg_get_expr(a2.adbin, a2.adrelid)
```

to get a string representation of the column default value.